# Thunderbird ADDON: port.postmessage() does not work reliably

Tags: javascript, python, thunderbird-addon

I am trying, and trying, and trying , … to debug an addon that I wrote for Thunderbird 78.10.2. It sends message to a python backend and then reads the reply back:

```js
async function buttonListener(tab) {
    
    tabId = tab.id;
    
    port = browser.runtime.connectNative("backendMyEd");
    
    cD = await browser.compose.getComposeDetails(tab.id);
    
    var body = extractBody(cD);
    
    await port.postMessage(body);
    
    port.onMessage.addListener(getReply);
}
```

The listener is just a python script that is doing:

```py
def get_message():
    
    if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
    
        len_field = sys.stdin.read(4)
    
    else:
    
        len_field = sys.stdin.buffer.read(4)
    
    if not len_field:
    
        sys.exit(0)
    
    message_length = struct.unpack('=I', len_field)[0]
    
    message = sys.stdin.read(message_length)  <=====
    
    return json.loads(message)
```

This works half the time but not always. When it doesn’t, my printfs tell me that it’s stuck in stdin read, but `port.postMessage()` has returned. If I quit TB or remove my add on, the `sys.stdin.read()` finishes.

Several things come to mind:

Is there a flush needed after `port.postMessage()`? maybe its not flushing all the time?

could it be related to message size? i tested with different sizes, and for less than 8k it often works. For larger ones, it seems to not work more often.

Could there be some special characters in message causing this?

4. Something to do with JS being single threaded? But the function is async, and python should be a different process. I also tried doing a fork in python, still hangs off and on in `sys.stdin.read()`...

Any ideas on whats going on, or how I could debug further?

Comment: Some Tips: add the python tag to attract more views, and also fix the code fences properly, good luck :D

Comment: Thanks veggie lover :).  I actually added sleep before the post call, and it still causes the stdin read in python to hang often. So i concluded it was not related to fencing... But, still a good idea to put on TODO list.